# In QTP, Facing error in "Call to existing action"

Tags: qtp

In `QTP`, I have called many actions using `Call to existing action` and it is working fine in the same machine. If i use different client machine to run the scripts, only the first test runs and the rest of the action is not running. When i opened the scripts manually from `QTP`, it shows -

```
Missing Action1 - it suggested to add relative path
```

Can any one please guide me on this?

Comment: should i add the function library path there?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to File > Settings, then go to Resources and associate the actions.

Comment: Still the same issue. Any other possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Look at your configured "QTP > menu > Options > Folders"-settings, as between your two QTP machines
(2) Do you have identical absolute paths for your scripts (including drive #'s)?  (I've found that flipping drives is a pain @! @## @@#$!!!)  Unfortunately you have to play lots of tricks to get the 'relative'-pathing really working as expected!  IMHO.